# Occasionally the class with load, and sometimes it decides not to work at all

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

```
[02:15:10 ERROR]: Could not pass event InventoryClickEvent to fetus v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:302) ~[spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at co.aikar.timings.TimedEventExecutor.execute(TimedEventExecutor.java:74) ~[spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:517) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1735) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:31) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:9) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:44) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:867) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:382) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:806) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:708) [spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/opinasdfpi/fetus/classes/zombieClass/zombieClass
        at dev.opinasdfpi.fetus.events.spawnitems.selector.click(selector.java:426) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor203.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:300) ~[spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.opinasdfpi.fetus.classes.zombieClass.zombieClass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:102) ~[spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:87) ~[spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at dev.opinasdfpi.fetus.events.spawnitems.selector.click(selector.java:426) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor203.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:300) ~[spigot.jar:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: ClassNotFoundException -> looks like you don't have all you need on your path.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: If I've referenced all my classes, how is there a problem accessing them?

Comment: I can call you in my living room, but as long as you are not in my living room, you are not likely to hear it, now are you? It doesn't matter that you reference it, if the environment on which you execute your code doesn't know the class you are trying to call

Comment: How do I check for a class that exists, but the error returns that it doesn't?

Comment: you can't check that at runtime, you need to make sure to add it to your environment before execution.

Answer (score 1):

The *Classpath* defines where Java should load it's classes from. Depending if you run from console or IDE the settings will differ. If you use plain javac you can add libs the following way:

```
javac HelloWorld.java -cp /my/path/to/lib/mylibrary.jar
```

You can debug where classes are loaded from using a JRE parameter:

```
java -verbose HelloWorld
```

You will find same parameters in any IDE. In IntelliJ e.g. it's the dropdown next to the "run" button on the upper right.

Having said this I think this classname smells like misconfiguration in zombieClass:

```
zombieClass.zombieClass
```

Maybe in some config you need to write **zombieClass.class** instead.

(By the way classes in Java should be *CamelCase* starting with big letter. Also I would not call any package "classes" as everything is mainly a class, better try using domain specific names, e.g. "characters")

Also this line looks fishy (the "Unknown Source"):

```
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
```

Have a look where you load the class from and debug to see which classes are really loaded! Behaviour can e.g. change as Java doesn't ensure a specific order of classes, so I had once an issue because files were ordered differently in Windows and Linux. So also avoid classes loaded twice (e.g. by loading two libs with same class).